# Bounded function inside series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If I have a factor inside a series that is bounded $\forall n \in \mathbb{R}$ (but this should apply also if it is *definitely* bounded, so for $n \to +\infty$) can I just study the convergence/divergence of the series without the factor?

For example, if I have to study the absolute convergence of the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^\alpha}\right)(\sqrt[n]{n} - \sqrt[n+1]{n}) \text{, } \alpha \in \mathbb{R}
$$
I can just say that $\left|\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^\alpha}\right)\right|$ is bounded to $[0,1]$ and so
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^\alpha}\right)\right|(\sqrt[n]{n} - \sqrt[n+1]{n}) < \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt[n]{n} - \sqrt[n+1]{n}
$$
but can I do the same for $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1 - \cos\left(\frac{1}{x^\alpha}\right)\right)(\sqrt[n]{n} - \sqrt[n+1]{n})$? Because $1 - \cos\left(\frac{1}{x^\alpha}\right)$ is bounded to $[0,2]$ instead!

One way I could *motivate* this is
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1 - \cos\left(\frac{1}{x^\alpha}\right)\right)(\sqrt[n]{n} - \sqrt[n+1]{n}) \text{ converges} \iff \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1 - \cos\left(\frac{1}{x^\alpha}\right)}{2}(\sqrt[n]{n} - \sqrt[n+1]{n}) \text{ converges}
$$
now $\frac{1 - \cos\left(\frac{1}{x^\alpha}\right)}{2}$ is bounded to $[0,1]$, so I can say that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1 - \cos\left(\frac{1}{x^\alpha}\right)}{2}(\sqrt[n]{n} - \sqrt[n+1]{n}) < \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt[n]{n} - \sqrt[n+1]{n}
$$
but is this a consistent method?

Comment: Food for thought: the constant function $0$ is bounded, and if you multiply it to the terms of a series, then the result is always convergent, regardless of the convergence of the original series. You might also appreciate [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3065621/for-a-n-b-n-c-n-with-a-n-leq-b-n-leq-c-n-convergence-of-sum-limits/).

Comment: @TheoBendit and it is true that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{0 \cdot a_n}$ converges when $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}$ does. I just cannot say anything when $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}$ diverges. Or am I wrong?

Comment: You are right. The linked question helps show the other direction: when $\sum a_n$ converges and $b_n$ is bounded, then $\sum a_n b_n$ converges too. Note, this gives you the other direction if you can also show that $b_n^{-1}$ is bounded.

Comment: @TheoBendit thanks! So, for example, I cannot say that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\sin(n)a_n}$ diverges when $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}$ does because $\csc(x)$ is not a bounded function. But if I have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(2 + \sin(x))a_n}$ I can, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right (excusing the $x$ that should be an $n$).

Comment: @TheoBendit yes, I was considering more generally $\csc : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Thanks!